# jQuery Mobile - change page with additional attributes

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement simple feature into jQuery Mobile, but with no chance.

I have a list (listview - dynamic created) and i need, after someone click on element, to change a page with additional attribute (e.g id).

thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean additional attribute?

Comment: If i have a list, every item (li>a) have unique id. I need change a page, with a id of item which was be clicked. Hope it helps :)

Comment: `$(li a).on("click", function (){ $.mobile.changePage("#" + this.id); });`.

Comment: thanks for response, but my situation is little bit different. I have a static view (e.g. #page-detail). And after click, i need change a page to #page-detail and after change create content of #page-detail dynamic. If you know what i mean. My page is just skeleton for data, which should be loaded dynamic .

Comment: Sorry, still didn't get what you mean.

Comment: So if i use your example, $.mobile.changePage("#" + this.id);, i have to have page where name is id. e.g. #1 or #2. But i need have just one page (#page) and use something like $.mobile.changePage("#page", this.id); where second parameter is my custom attribute (based on record which was be clicked)